# Emacs: suppress indent after && in shell-script-mode

Tags: emacs, shell-script, indentation

In shell-script-mode, when a line ends in `&&`, Emacs will indent the following line. Is there a way to switch that off? (I am concatenating most of my statements with `&&`. This gives finer control over error handling than `set -e`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation code for shell scripts has been completely rewritten around the time of Emacs-24 to use SMIE, and SMIE itself has evolved during the life of Emacs-24, so the best solution may depend on your exact Emacs version, but with Emacs-24.5 you should be able to do:

- Go to the line with incorrect indentation.
- type `M-x smie-config-show-indent` which should show you the rules
  that were used to indent this line.  It might say something like:

  > Rules used: :before "&&" -> (column . 19), :before "[" -> nil, :elem basic -> 4, :after "&&" -> nil

Sadly the `(column . 19)` in there mostly implies that you won't be able to change this behavior in a "simple" way (i.e. you can't change it with `smie-config-set-indent`).

But I think the following should do it:

```
(defun my-sh-smie-sh-rules (origfun kind token)
  (pcase (cons kind token)
    (`(:before . "&&") nil)
    (_ (funcall origfun kind token))))
(advice-add 'sh-smie-sh-rules :around #'my-sh-smie-sh-rules)
```

You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug` and request that such a config be made easier, since it's probably a fairly common indentation style.